# Calling value in PHP from a jQuery serialized array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have an ajax call that sends data from serialized checkboxes (among other) to a php file:

```
$("#button1").click(function(e) {
    var category_id = {};
    category_id['datumanf'] = $("#datumanf").datepicker().val();
    category_id['checkboxvalue'] = $('.checkboxes').serialize();
    console.log($('.checkboxes').serialize());
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "allgemein.php
        dataType: "html",
        data: category_id,
        success: function(response) {
            $("#resulttable").show().html(response);

        }
    });
});
```

The html checkboxes look like this (they contain bits of SQL):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" name="checkb[]" value="SYSTEM LIKE '%system%'">
```

When I try to call their name via POST in php like

```
echo $_POST['checkb'];
```

it's always empty. I tried variations like `$_POST['checkb[1]'];` or `$_POST['checkb[]'];` it's always empty. 
However when i call the whole array `echo $_POST['checkboxvalues'];` I get the same as `console.log`.
I need the values singularily however. How can I do that?

Comment: Why not use `$('form#formId').serialize()` to pass all the data to PHP?

Comment: @Ben I didn't know about .serialize until recently, that's why :) Would you think this could solve it, i.e. is the 'mixture' of serialized variables and 'direct' variables in `var category_id` the problem?

Comment: Not sure, haven't tried to serialize just one field before but I have achieved your desired result countless times using form.serialize(). And I don't think you need to set dataType either.

Comment: Have you tried $_POST['checkb'][0];?

Comment: @cngodles i have not!! Will try this asap, thank you!

Comment: @cngodles no i couldn't make it work like that :/ i went for a different solution approach in the end :)